# Inheritance in bounded type parameters to limite types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract class with a generic using a bounded type parameter to limit this type:

```
public abstract class AbstractCreator<T extends Request> {
     ....
}
```

Then I have multiple children from AbstractCreator and one uses another bounded type parameter, like next:

```
public abstract class AbstractBigCreator<U extends BigRequest> extends AbstractCreator<U> {
    U request;
    ...
}
```

---

The interfaces bounded types are like next:

```
public interface Request<T extends Some> {
     T getRequest();
}
public interface BigRequest<T extends SomeOther> extends Request<T> {

}
```

My problem is this child with another bounded type parameter is limiting to its the father class bounded type parameter in the class itself instead of this type parameter. So if I call the method `getRequest()`from `U request` I get that it is `<T extends Some>` instead of `<T extends SomeOther>`.

I expect:

```
U request;
request.getRequest(); //Class <T extends SomeOther>
```

But instead I get:

```
U request;
request.getRequest(); //Class <T extends Some>
```

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Why can't you have 2 (bounded) type parameters in `AbstractBigCreator`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but I cannot; for me the inferred type of U extends `BigRequest` as expected.  Where are you seeing the fact that the compiler thinks it extends `Request`?  is it when you invoke a method on it or something?

Comment: Updated question. Now is more specific.

Comment: `AbstractBigCreator` extends from `AbstractRequestCreator`, which you aren't showing. Do you mean `AbstractCreator` instead of `AbstractRequestCreator`?

Comment: Another question, just to clarify what your problem is... You are saying that the `U` type of the request in `AbstractBigCreator` is `Request` instead of `BigRequest`? Or are you saying that the return type of the method `getRequest` of the `U request` attribute in `AbstractBigCreator` is `Some` instead of `SomeOther`?

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffne sorry I've updated my question, I mean `AbstractCreator` instead of `AbstractRequestCreator`. And related to return type, I'm saying the return type of method `getReques`t is `Some` instead of `SomeOther`. Sorry if the question is not clear.

Comment: I have made it work just overriding the methods of Request in BigRequest, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Pau due to covariance, in the child interface, you can return a subtype of the type returned on the method of the parent interface, when overriding a method. So now `getRequest()` in `BigRequest` returns `SomeOther`, while before it was returning just `Some`, exactly as it was declared in the parent interface `Request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **not** that the `request` attribute is of type `Request` instead of `BigRequest` in your `AbstractBigCreator` class.

The actual problem is that your `BigRequest` interface is extending the `Request` interface, so you are inheriting the definition of the `T getRequest()` method. And in `Request`, the `T` type is bounded to `Some`, and so is in `BigRequest`.

The easiest solution is to redefine the `T getRequest()` method in the `BigRequest` interface, so that [*covariance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_return_type) is applied to the return type of the `getRequest` method. This means that the `getRequest` method of the `BigRequest` interface would return `SomeOther` instead of `Some`.

Just do this:

```
public interface BigRequest<T extends SomeOther> extends Request<T> {

    @Override
    T getRequest();
}
```

And you'll be able to access `SomeOther` after calling `request.getRequest()` in `AbstractBigCreator`.